# How do I overload `float()` for a custom class?

Tags: python, floating-point, operator-overloading, overloading

How do I implement a method that overloads `float()`, i.e. it is called when an instance of a class I've written is passed to `float()`?

I am starting to write my own `Fraction` class:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, num = 0, denom = 1):
        self.num = float(num)
        self.denom = float(denom)
```

Now I want to be able to do this:

```
float(Fraction())
```

I tried using the below method, but that didn't work.

```
def float(self):
    return self.num / self.denom
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you do me a favour? My question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938329/why-use-a-flat-list-in-heapsort had gotten closed for being to vague. I edited it and now it seems like a perfectly legit question for SO.

Comment: Thing is, my account just got automatically banned because of that and I can't ask any more questions, so could you please upvote it if you think my question is good enough?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ??? Atleast a reply saying "Yes" or "No"?

Comment: yeah, +1, looks a fair Q to me

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks a lot. If it wouldn't be too much, could you also flag the question for moderator's attention so it can be reopened? ( Apparently, that privilege has been stripped too :< )

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Do you mean that you had enough rep to cast a reopen vote?

Comment: Yes, 127k rep gives me that priv

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Cool... BTW, how many votes are needed to reopen the question? And how many have been cast? I need to know how many more moderators I have to hunt before I regain my former privileges.

Comment: Oh, and thanks a lot BTW. When do these election things happen?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Define the [`__float__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) special method on your class.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __float__(self):
         return 0.0

float(MyClass())   # 0.0
```

Note that this method must return a `float`! The calculation `self.num / self.denom`, returns an `int` by default in versions of Python prior to 3.0 assuming both operands are integers.  In this case you'd just make sure one of the operands is a float: `float(self.num) / self.denom` for example.

Comment: I _am_ using ints throughout my code for `self.num` and `self.denom`. 10x for the answer.

Comment: What _would_ happen if you didn't return a float?

Comment: You get a `TypeError` exception.

Comment: @YatharthROCK: Basically, you will create an unstable black hole inside your python interpreter and the universe will be destroyed. I think kindall is just pointing out the fact that `/` denotes integer division by default in <= python 2.x and floating point division in python 3.x. You should be aware of this.

Comment: @kindall: So when you call one of the special methods, it doesn't just execute the overloaded method, it still passes through the special method?

Comment: if you *are* using Python <3.0 , you can always use a future import to get float-returning division, i.e.: `from __future__ import division`. Then `self.num / self.denom` will work fine.