# Allowing a subclass to have different *args and **kwargs from its parent class in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

The following code is the initialization method of a basic Angle object with float as its parent class.

```
class Angle(float):
    def __init__(self, value, vertex2 = None, vertex3 = None, atype = 'convex'):

        #type-checking for the input args
        try:
            #checks for value arg
            angle = value
            if not (0 < value < 360):
                angle %= 360
        except TypeError:
            #checks for three-vertice args
            try:
                angle = three_point_angle(value, vertex2, vertex3)
                #three_point_angle is a function to calculate the
                #convex angle between three vertices (i.e. at vertex2)
                if atype == 'concave':
                    angle = 360 - angle
                self._vdict = {}
                for pos, vert in enumerate([value, vertex2, vertex3]):
                    self._vdict[pos] = vert
            except:
                raise TypeError(\
                    "You may only specify either an angle value, or three vertices from which \
                    to calculate the angle. You input a %s, %s and %s value." % (\
                        type(value), type(vertex2), type(vertex3)))
        self.angle = angle
```

The idea behind this class is that you can either input a value for the angle, or specify three vertices (and an optional angle type parameter) to automatically calculate the angle. In the end, self.angle is always initialized, and this is where all the arithmetic takes place (so `__add__(self, other)` would affect `self.angle`).

The reason it inherits from `float` is to inherit its magic methods for reflective and augmented assignment, which are all performed on `self.angle`.

The problem arises when one tries to input three values for the vertices. Since it inherits from `float`, it can't take more than one argument, and as such raises an error. How would I work around this? My guess is that I would have to create a `__new__` method for `Angle`, such that it would be invoked instead of the superclass', but I have no clue where I'd even start with that or even if it's the right/best way to go about this.

Comment: What is the full error traceback? I don't think the problem is what you're describing.

Comment: `a = Angle(Vertex(0, 0), Vertex(0, 10), Vertex(10, 10))`
Leads to

`TypeError: float() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to inherit from float. You're incorrect in thinking that magic methods are performed on self.angle; they're just performed on self. Try the following code:

```
class Angle(float):
    def __init__(self, x):
         self.angle = x
    def double(self):
         self.angle *= 2
a = Angle(1)
a.double()
print a # prints 1.0
print a.angle # prints 2
a *= 5
print a # prints 5.0
print a.angle # throws AttributeError
```

`a.angle` isn't affected by magic methods, nor is `float(a)` affected by operations on `a.angle`. `float`s are immutable, so `a *= 5` created a new float, with different attributes.

So, if you change `Angle` to inherit from `Object` instead of `float`, you can control initialization, without losing any convenience.

Answer (score 1):

See this related question:

[How to overload `float()` for a custom class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034097/how-to-overload-float-for-a-custom-class-in-python)

then change

```
class Angle(float):
```

to

```
class Angle(object):
```