# Why do I get TypeError, when trying to find the max element of a heap with function 'nlargest'?

Tags: python, typeerror, heapq

I was trying to find the maximum element of a heap and found a function [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) to use.

Then got this error at the line commented below:

```
TypeError at line 10: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.
```

So here is the code:

```
from heapq import *
from math import ceil

number_of_elements, size_of_window = 10, 10
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
first_window = sorted(array[:size_of_window])
lower_set = first_window[:ceil(size_of_window / 2)]
lower_set_heap = heapify(lower_set)
print(nlargest(1,lower_set_heap))  # got TypeError here
```

Comment: That's only eight lines, but the error is on line ten. Please make sure you provide a [mcve]! In any case, you unexpectedly have `None` somewhere, understand/fix that.

Comment: Please post the full traceback and code. The error suggests line 10, but there are only 8 in what you've posted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A side note - `array` is Python class name, try to avoid it as variable name. -unless you mean it.

Answer (score 1):

`heapify` [modifies the argument in-place](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/heapq.html?highlight=heapify#heapq.heapify):

> `heapq.heapify(x)`
>
> Transform list `x` into a heap, in-place, in linear time.

Thus, in `lower_set_heap = heapify(lower_set)`, `lower_set_heap` will be `None`:

```
>>> lower_set_heap = heapify(lower_set)
>>> lower_set_heap is None
True
```

You should just write `heapify(lower_set)` and then `lower_set` is your heap:

```
>>> heapify(lower_set) # modifies `lower_set`
>>> print(nlargest(1,lower_set))
[5]
```

Comment: Although hinting the issue "Transform _list_ .. __in-place__"  which means the list `lower_set` given as argument should be further processed as result instead of the return value (which will always be `None`), IMO the question should be clarified first. A proper error-output or full stacktrace could help here first.

Comment: @hc_dev, I simply pasted OP's code into the REPL and got the same (except for the line number) error as in the question. Not sure what there's to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Why do we need to `heapify` fist?
Instead we could just call `nlargest` directly?

```
from heapq
from math import ceil

number_of_elements, size_of_window = 10, 10
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

first_window = sorted(array[:size_of_window])
lower_set = first_window[:ceil(size_of_window / 2)]

# (1) just return the largest
print(heapq.nlargest(1, lower_set))

# (2) fixed solution: why heapify first?
heapq.heapify(lower_set)  # Attention: modifies list in_place
print(heapq.nlargest(1,lower_set))
```

Both print the same:

```
[5]
[5]
```

See also

- DEV Community: [Python: using heapq module to find n largest items](https://dev.to/v_it_aly/python-using-heapq-module-to-find-n-largest-items-1b3o)
- [Why use a flat list in heapsort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938329/why-use-a-flat-list-in-heapsort/9938383#9938383)

Answer (score 0):

Do not store heapify method result because it returns **None**, if you want to keep heapified array do the following instead.

```
from heapq import *
from math import ceil

number_of_elements, size_of_window = 10, 10
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
first_window = sorted(array[:size_of_window])
lower_set = first_window[:ceil(size_of_window / 2)]
lower_set_heap = lower_set.copy()   #copy the required array
heapify(lower_set_heap)     #perform heapify operation
print(nlargest(1,lower_set_heap))
```

Output:

```
[5]
```