# Complexity of Heapsort algorithm

Tags: algorithm

In the book is written:

> The worst-case running time of heapsort is (nlgn). This is clear since
>   sorting has a lower bound of (nlgn)

But can someone help me and show me explicitly that the lower-bound of this function is equal to Omega(nlgn)?

Comment: what about this? http://cs.txstate.edu/~ch04/webtest/teaching/courses/5329/lectures/heap-comp.pdf

Comment: Wikipedia also [has the proof idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list)

Comment: The book is inaccurate. Comparing the lower bound common to all comparison-based sorting algorithms and and the actual upper bound on the running time of a particular algorithm is comparing apples and oranges, and does nothing to show why heap sort is *no worse* than O(n lg n).

Comment: @chepner is right. get another book. What is this books name btw?

Comment: Unless the quote is supposed to read "... is Omega(n lg n)", I suppose.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589988/lower-bound-on-heapsort

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the book is drawing on the fact that heapsort is a comparison-based sorting algorithm in that statement. So automatically, this paradigm of sorting algorithms have already been shown to have a lower-bound of Omega(nlgn):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list

Comment: The asker is looking for an **explicit** proof, not an **implicit** one, i.e. an analysis of the algorithm, not simply saying it takes as long as it does because it's a comparison-based sorting algorithm.